# Using ImageDrawables in a TextView vs ImageView+TextView

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there any (even if infinitesimal) memory/speed advantage if I use a `DrawableLeft` property of a `TextLabel` to show a image beside text instead of using a two objects (`ImageView` and `TextLabel`) adjusted next to next in a layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DrawableLeft solution would use just one object or widget, while the other one takes probaly three, as it may need a container to envelop image and text object. I would go for the one object solution, if it does job properly, as it would be more efficient both memory and speed wise.

Comment: Yeah, the [TextView][1] sourcecode confirms that. All these drawables are objects which are literally **drawn**, saves a lot of overheads.


  [1]: http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java